# Could someone shed some light on GITkit v2

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, openid

I am trying to integrate `GITkit v2` ( https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/v2/acguide ); I have problems comprehending a few things in the documentation, and was hoping that someone could shed some light on it.

1) Is the callback in the xample using `HTTPS` to prevent certain cross-site scripting ("`XSS`") vectors, and thus, highly recommended for the callback? If so, is it also recommended for`loginUrl`, and possibly others?

2) Inside the `identitytoolkit.setConfig({})` you have to specify the `HomeUrl`, but it seems that `GITkit v2` is no longer redirecting to your homepage automatically, according to the 1. `{/homeUrl}` section ( why do you have to specify it twice? )

3) After the callback logic has been performed ( knows whether user is already registered, or not ) should the HTML in 1. `{/homeUrl}` be echo'd onto the callback page? Could someone explain me the exact workflow of `GITkit v2`?

I have been reading for the past few hours, and I just cannot figure these problems out.
Very much appreciated for any answer ( even if it does not answer all of them ), any additional information is appreciated too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback receives response from the IDP, and it might therefore contain personal information from OAuth. It is better to use HTTPS for the callback, as well as legacy login, and registration.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.accountchooser.com/client.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('identitytoolkit', '2', {packages: ['store']});
  jQuery(function() {
    var homeUrl = '/'; // Your home page URL.
    var account = {
      email: 'user@idp.com',
      displayName: 'User Name',
      photoUrl: 'http://website.com/img/user.png'
    };
  window.google.identitytoolkit.storeAccount(account, homeUrl);
  });
</script>
```

Should indeed be posted on the callback page (after your logic), make sure to replace the default values with the values returned by the OAuth - displayName, and photoUrl are optional.

Finally, the homeUrl inside the widget is used to redirect users after the legacy login. :-)